# Variable may not have been initialized (a)

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class lab3
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         Scanner input= new Scanner (System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter the height (feet;");
         double height;
         height= input.nextDouble();
         double width;
         width= input.nextDouble();
         double area;
         final double GALLONS_PER_SQUARE_FEET=150.0;
         double gallons;
         gallons = area/GALLONS_PER_SQUARE_FEET;
         System.out.println("The amount of paint is " + gallons + " gallons.");
     }//end main
}//end class
```

> lab3.java:19: error: variable area might not have been initialized
>   gallons = area /GALLONS_PER_SQUARE_FEET;

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't initialize it before

```
double area;
double gallons;
```

This is a declaration, not an initialization.

```
 double area = 1.0;
 double gallons = 0.0;
```

This is an initialization.

Comment: `area` should be initialized with 1, not 0.

Comment: Thanks @ Luiggi Mendoza.

Answer (score 0):

You have `double area;`. However, you never assigned `area` a value before using it in the equation.

```
gallons = area/GALLONS_PER_SQUARE_FEET;
```

To fix it, you need to initialize `area` by assigning it a value before using it.

e.g.

```
double area = 1.0;
```